# JPA Hibernate MapsId for grand child

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to save an entity in JPA 2.1.
I have three tables - MVCollection, MVCollectionVersion (which is versions of MVCollection) and MVBelongsCollection(which is the items belonging to a version).
The Primary Key of MVCollection is a generated sequence number.
When I generate a collection with a version (without any items) I am using @MapsId, and the ID generated is used within the child. However I cannot seem to understand how I can replicate this with the items.

Here are snippets from the code so far :

```
@Entity
public class MVCollection {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
         generator = "MVCOLLECTION_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MVCOLLECTION_SEQ", 
        sequenceName = "VMD.MVCOLLECTION_SEQ")
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MVCOLLECTIONID")
   private Long id;
```

MVCollectionVersion

```
@Entity
public class MVCollectionVersion {
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "versionId", column = @Column(name = "MVCVSNID")) })

    private MVCollectionVersionId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "MVCOLLECTIONID", referencedColumnName = "MVCOLLECTIONID"),
     })
    @MapsId("mvCollectionId")
    private MVCollection mvCollection;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="mvCollectionVersion", cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
   private List<MVBelongsCollection> mvCollectionItems;
```

MVCollectionId

```
@Embeddable
public class MVCollectionVersionId implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2551937096790427792L;
    private Long mvCollectionId;
    private Integer versionId;
```

MVBelongsCollection

```
@Entity
public class MVCollectionItems

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "managedViewId", column = @Column(name = "MANAGEDVIEWID")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "mvCollectionId", column = @Column(name = "MVCOLLECTIONID")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "versionId", column = @Column(name = "MVCVSNID")) })

    private MVBelongsCollectionId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "MVCOLLECTIONID", referencedColumnName = "MVCOLLECTIONID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "MVCVSNID", referencedColumnName = "MVCVSNID") })
    private MVCollectionVersion mvCollectionVersion;
```

and finally MVBelongsCollectionId

```
@Embeddable
public class MVBelongsCollectionId implements Serializable{


/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column ( name = "MANAGEDVIEWID", nullable = false, precision = 38)
    private Long managedViewId;

    @Column ( name = "MVCOLLECTIONID", nullable = false, precision = 38)
    private Long mvCollectionId;

    @Column ( name = "MVCVSNID", nullable = false, precision = 38)
    private Integer versionId;
```

if I try to create a collection with a version and with belongsCollection items, the create fails as it states the mvCollectionId field is null
"ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("VMD"."MVBELONGSCOLLECTION"."MVCOLLECTIONID")"
Therefore I tried to add @MapsId as I had done with MVCollectionVersion.

```
public class MVBelongsCollection {

/**
 * primary key
 */
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "managedViewId", column = @Column(name = "MANAGEDVIEWID")),
        //@AttributeOverride(name = "mvCollectionId", column = @Column(name = "MVCOLLECTIONID")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "versionId", column = @Column(name = "MVCVSNID")) })
    private MVBelongsCollectionId id;


/**
 * collection that this joins to.
 */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("mvCollectionId")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "MVCOLLECTIONID", referencedColumnName = "MVCOLLECTIONID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "MVCVSNID", referencedColumnName = "MVCVSNID") })
    private MVCollectionVersion mvCollectionVersion;
```

However in Eclipse, this shows an error on the @ManyToOne Annotation of

```
The type of the ID mapped by the relationship 'mvCollectionVersion' does not agree with the primary key class of the target entity.
```

If I start the process, I get 
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: MVBelongsCollection column: MVCVSNID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

I have tried adding insertable = false, and updatable = false to my @JoinColumn, the @AttributeOVerride and the underlying ID class but still get the same error.
This only happens when the @MapsId is present.

I am now at a loss how I get the MVBelongsCollection to use the generated MVCollectionId, or how I can stop both the eclipse and the runtime error.

If anyone can help I would be grateful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found the error of my ways...

I needed to use the same embeddedId throughout.
Therefore the MVBelongsCollectionId needed to change to include the embedded id of the parent class:

```
@Embeddable
public class MVBelongsCollectionId implements Serializable{


    /**
    * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "mvCollectionId", column = @Column(name = "MVCOLLECTIONID", nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "versionId", column = @Column(name = "MVCVSNID", nullable = false, precision = 8, scale = 0)) 

    })
    MVCollectionVersionId collectionVersionId;

    @Column ( name = "MANAGEDVIEWID", nullable = false, precision = 38)
    private Long managedViewId;

   ....
```